# What is to be done when an accepted answer is factually wrong?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

The accepted answer for this question - [Would killing ISIS journalists be considered a war crime? If so, could ISIS use the ICC?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/would-killing-isis-journalists-be-considered-a-war-crime-if-so-could-isis-use?rq=1) - is wrong as I've pointed out in the comment. What is to be done for such cases?

Comment: I would suggest posting a correct answer that also explains why the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: Vote down, move on. Being accepted means the user asking the question liked it the most, nothing more, nothing less. They're not pinned to the top any more either.